# Добавить url в fail2ban в ignore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, fail2ban

Задача следующая - есть строка с лога

`2021/06/29 16:05:32 [error] 122279#122279: *434 limiting requests, excess: 1.702 by zone "one", client: 192.168.0.1, server: www.tests.com, request: "GET /test/online HTTP/1.0", host: "www.tests.com"`

Как пройтись регуляркой (Ignoreregex) для игнорирования всех запросов на

> /test/online

в fail2ban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем собственно? Когда это можно снять в самом nginx, например:

```
location = /test/online {
   # или выключить log-entry:
   #error_log /dev/null crit;
   # или "выключить" limit-req:
   limit_req_dry_run on;
}
```

но если всё же нужно в fail2ban:

```
ignoreregex = request: "[A-Z]+ /test/online [^"]+", host: "[^"]+"$
```